# How do I add item to the list of items in the invoice with the requested item quantity without changing the existing quantity of the item in db

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, database-design, orm

`So now I want to be able to set the values of the item to add to item list in the invoice with the values in the addItemToInvoiceRequest, without affecting the values of the optional item returned from the db. When I set the value of the item to add to the invoice list with the addItemToInvoiceRequest parameters and call the addItemToInvoice endpoint using postman, it changes the state of the item already saved in the db. Please give me a solution.

This the Invoice model

package com.hand2hand.hand2hand_dev.data.models;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "INVOICES")
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "invoiceID", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    private long invoiceNumber;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    private String invoiceDescription;
    @NotBlank(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String sellerFullName;
    @NotNull(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Address sellerAddress;
    @NotBlank(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String sellerPhoneNumber;
    @NotBlank(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String buyerFullName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String buyerPhoneNumber;
    @NotBlank(message = "Fields cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String buyerEmailAddress;
    @Embedded
    private BankDetails paymentInfo;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id")
    private TransactionRecord transactionRecord;
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MMM d, y")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "invoice_item",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Item> invoiceItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Invoice invoice = (Invoice) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, invoice.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

This is my Item model

```
package com.hand2hand.hand2hand_dev.data.models;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "ITEMS")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "itemID", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @NotNull(message = "Item name can't be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Item name can't be empty")
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Item description can't be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Item description can't be empty")
    private String description;
    @NotNull(message = "Price  can't be null")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @NotNull(message = "Quantity  can't be null")
    private Integer itemQuantity = 0;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_id")
    private Inventory inventory;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceItems")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Invoice> invoice = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), item.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

This is the request DTO

```
package com.hand2hand.hand2hand_dev.data.dto.request;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class AddItemToInvoiceRequest {
    private String itemId;
    private Integer quantity;
    private String appUserId;
    private String invoiceId;
}
```

This is the addItemToInvoice implementation

```
public String addItemToInvoice(AddItemToInvoiceRequest addItemToInvoiceRequest) {
        Optional<Item> optionalItem = inventoryService.findItem(addItemToInvoiceRequest.getItemId(),
            addItemToInvoiceRequest.getAppUserId());
        if (optionalItem.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ItemException("Item not found");
        }

        Item itemToAdd = optionalItem.get();
        int requestedQuantity = addItemToInvoiceRequest.getQuantity();
        if (itemToAdd.getItemQuantity() < requestedQuantity) {
        throw new ItemException("Item quantity not sufficient");
        }

        Invoice invoice = invoiceRepository.findById(addItemToInvoiceRequest.getInvoiceId())
            .orElseThrow(()-> new InvoiceException(String.format("invoice id %s not found", addItemToInvoiceRequest.getInvoiceId())));

        List<Item> itemsToAdd = invoice.getInvoiceItems();
        int existingQuantity = 0;
        for (Item item : itemsToAdd) {
            if (item.getId().equals(itemToAdd.getId())) {
            existingQuantity = item.getItemQuantity();
            itemsToAdd.remove(item);
            break;
            }
        }
        itemToAdd.setItemQuantity(existingQuantity + requestedQuantity);
                           itemToAdd.setTotalPrice(itemToAdd.getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(itemToAdd.getItemQuantity())));

        itemsToAdd.add(itemToAdd);

        BigDecimal invoiceTotalPrice = itemsToAdd.stream()
                .map(Item::getTotalPrice)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
        invoice.setTotalAmount(invoiceTotalPrice);
        invoiceRepository.save(invoice);

        return "Item added";
    }
```